# Use the slice method to create multiple pages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pagination, slice

I have created this Array:

```
let products = {
    data: [
      {
        productName: "Product1",
      },
      {
        productName: "Product2",
      },
      {
        productName: "Product3",
      },
      {
        productName: "Product4",
      },
      {
        productName: "Product5",
      },
      {
        multiple other products
      },
],
};
```

I want to loop through and display all of the objects in this Array. However, after 10 objects, I want the objects to move onto another page.

The page should display the first 10 objects within this Array. There should be a button the user can click to view the next 10 products. When the user clicks this button, the next 10 products should then be shown.

I want to loop through the objects, rather than manually add each of these pages.

However, all of these pages should be displayed using a single HTML, CSS and JavaScript file.

Buttons should be used in order to allow the user to switch between these pages.

Comment: You are describing several tasks. But this is not a platform to post tasks. This is a place where you can ask a specific question about a problem you have encountered in your attempt to code something. Where is your code? What is the question?

Comment: Try the `.slice` method, like `products.slice(index, index+10)`